# Problema para asignar varios autores a un trabajo

Tags: mysql, php7

tengo una base de datos mysql con dos tablas autores y documentos.
autores posee dos campos que son id_aut y nombre_aut; la tabla documentos tres campos id_doc, autores_doc, documento_doc.
Cargo la base y el campo de autores_doc contiene los datos del id_aut. ej (1,7,8)

En la pagina de autores tengo un listado de los mismos y un boton que pasa la variable id, que es igual al id_aut, pero al entrar a la pagina de documentos no logro ver ningún resultado, es como que no encuentra el id del autor.

Alguien que se apiade de mi.
Muchas Gracias
Antes del Html

```
<?php
$proc = TRUE;
require("codigo/config.php");
require("codigo/db_mysqli.class.php");
$dbLink = new db_mysqli();
require("codigo/funciones.php");
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
if (!isset ($id)){
Header("Location: mienbros.php"); 
}
$query="
SELECT
*
FROM
staff
WHERE
id_staff = $id
";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
if ($dbLink->num_rows > 0) {
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$nombre_staff = $row['nombre_staff'];
$foto_staff = $row['foto_staff'];
}
}
?>



En el cuerpo del html

    <?php
$query="
SELECT
*
FROM
documentos
WHERE
staff_doc = $id
ORDER BY
anio_doc ASC
";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
if ($dbLink->num_rows > 0) {
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$anio_doc = $row['anio_doc'];   
echo "            

                  <div class=\"anio\"><strong>AÑO $anio_doc</strong></div>\n";
?>  
      <?php
$query="
SELECT
*
FROM
documentos
Left Join staff ON staff.id_staff = documentos.staff_doc
WHERE
anio_doc = $anio_doc
ORDER BY
fecha_doc ASC
";
$aRes = $dbLink->query($query);
if ($dbLink->num_rows > 0) {
foreach($aRes AS $row) {
$fecha_doc = FormatDateTime($row["fecha_doc"], 2);
$tit_doc = $row['tit_doc'];
$descr_doc = $row['descr_doc'];
$arch_doc = $row['arch_doc'];
$otros_doc = $row['otros_doc'];
$staff_doc = $row['staff_doc'];
$nombre_staff = $row['nombre_staff'];

echo "                  
                  <div class=\"recuadro\">
                    <div>$fecha_doc</div>
                    <div><b>$tit_doc</b></div>
                    <div class=\"mb-4\">$descr_doc</div>
                    <div class=\"mb-3\">Autores</div>
                    <div>$nombre_staff &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div>$otros_doc &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                      <div class=\"leer_mas1 float-right\"><a href=\"images/archivos/$arch_doc\" target=\"_blank\">ARCHIVO</a></div>
                        <div class=\"clearfix\"></div>
                  </div>\n";
    }
  } 
?>
<?php
    }
  } 
?>
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro! Vendría muy bien que escribieras el código para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Va mejor la pregunta.. yo sigo sin entender en donde de todo tu codigo esta el problema, porque no se que es cada parte.

Answer (score 3):

Es porque tu necesitas una relacion del tipo muchos a muchos y en este caso estas usando una relacion uno a muchos, pero la estas usando mal ya que estás metiendo muchos id's en un solo campo y eso no te va a funcionar a menos que hagas malabares.

necesitas 3 tablas

documents

```
+----+-----------+
| Id |   Name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Documento |
+----+-----------+
```

authors

```
+----+---------+
| Id |  Name   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Autor 1 |
|  2 | Autor 2 |
|  3 | Autor 3 |
+----+---------+
```

Y por ultimo una tabla pivote, que contendrá el id de cada author que tenga acceso o sea dueño del documento.

author_document

```
+-----------+-------------+
| author_id | document_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |           1 |
|         2 |           1 |
|         3 |           1 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

Entonces ya de aqui es aplicar tu consulta ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM `documents` JOIN author_document ON documents.id = author_document.author_id
```

Esa consulta te trae los id's de los authores en una lista. Puede hacerla tan compleja como desees

Comment: En este caso, se puede usar por ejemplo `GROUP_CONCAT` cuando se quiera traer una lista de autores de un mismo documento.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, pero quise poner el ejemplo mñas sencillo de un JOIN para que él pudiera ir avanzando poco a poco.